# Ошибка синтаксиса в PHP

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

При отправке данных в таблицу на PhpMyAdmin (OpenServer) из формы на html, браузер выдает ошибку :

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "isset" in C:\OpenServer\domains\UchProc\Vvod_2.php on line 3**

Версия php - 8.0.1

html код :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Преподаватели </title>
    <style>
    tb {
    opacity: .5;
    }
    </style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(ships.gif); font-size:20pt; background-size: 100%"> <center>


    <form name="f1" action="Vvod_2.php" method="post">
    <table border="4" cellspacing="9" cellpadding="10" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/48/e8/62/48e8623f3f6f3da7e932ade8d6e2b0bd.png); font-size:15pt; color: white">
        <caption> Преподаватели </caption>
        <TBODY>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=number>Таб_преп</label></td>
            <td><input name=number></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=name> Фамилия: </label></td>
            <td><input name=Fam></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=name> Имя: </label></td>
            <td><input name=imya></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=name> Отечество: </label></td>
            <td><input name=otch></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=pol> Пол </label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="pol" value="Женский">Женский<br>
                <input type="radio" name="pol" value="Мужской">Мужской
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=data> Дата рождения </label></td>
            <td><input name=data></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="btn1" value="ВВЕСТИ ДАННЫЕ" type="submit">
    <input name="btn2" value="ОБНОВИТЬ ДАННЫЕ" type="submit">
    <input name="btn3" value="УДАЛИТЬ ДАННЫЕ" type="submit">
        <input  name="btn4" value="ОЧИСТИТЬ" type="reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

php код :

```
<?php
    
    if(isset($_POST[btn1])  isset($_POST[btn2])) \\браузер ругается на это

    {
        
    $qu = REPLACE prepodavateli SET tab_prep = '.$_POST['number'].',
    fam_prep = '.$_POST['Fam'].',
    name_prep = '.$_POST['imya'].',
    otch_prep = '.$_POST['otch'].',
    pol = '.$_POST['pol'].',
    data_roj = '.$_POST['data'].',
        echo $qu;

    }

    elseif(isset($_POST[btn3])) 
    {   
    $qu = DELETE from prepodavateli

    where number = '.$_POST['number'].';
    echo Запрос выполнен успешно!;
    }

    $c = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysqli_select_db($c,'uch_proc_171006');
    mysqli_query($c,'SET NAMES cp1251');
    mysqli_query($c,$qu);

?>
```

Comment: Ошибка когда появляется? У вас по коду $qu появляется когда 1, 2 и 3 нажаты, но когда нажата 4 то всё-равно в mysql запросы идут с $qu которой не существует - как тут ошибке не появиться то?

Comment: ошибка появляется, когда я нажимаю на btn1 (добавляю запись)

Comment: вероятно, потому что в логике проблема? `isset($_POST['btn1']) && isset($_POST['btn2'])` значит одновременно "нажаты" 1 и 2 - магия, никак иначе.. замените && на ||

Comment: Изначально вопрос был другой) Зачем поменяли содержимое?

Comment: Спасибо ! Я просто ПОЛНЫЙ новичек в sql 
Преподаватель дал исходник, сказал изучать и редактировать. Что смог изменил, а тут завис... Можно сказать, я только начинаю изучать язык 
Ещё раз спасибо за помощь )

Answer (score 1):

Ключи массива, которые не заключаются в кавычки воспринимаются как константы. Соответственно интерпретатор ищет константы с именами `btn1`, `btn2`, `btn3`

Нужно писать `$_POST['btn1']`, `$_POST['btn2']`, `$_POST['btn3']`

Также не хватает `&&` или `||`  между проверками

```
if (isset($_POST['btn1']) && isset($_POST['btn2'])) // или такое if (isset($_POST['btn1']) || isset($_POST['btn2']))
```

---

В целом у вас ещё полно ошибок в коде и почти не валиден ни в чём

Comment: Спасибо ! Исправил, теперь жалуется на 28 строку... Пойду думать )